# php вывод данных

Tags: php

Не могу вывести данные с бд 
db.php

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost'; // адрес сервера 
    $database = 'php2'; // имя базы данных
    $user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
    $password = ''; // пароль
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php'; // подключаем скрипт

// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

// выполняем операции с базой данных

$i ="SELECT * FROM articles active= 1";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$i);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
$d = mysql_free_result ( $result);
// закрываем подключение
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Моя ошибка
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\php\2\index.php on line 12

Comment: Сделайте var_dump($result) и посмотрите результат

Comment: @Дмитрий внимательно прочесть вопрос, то там написано содержимое $result

Comment: читайте свой sql запрос до тех пор пока не найдете там слово `where`

Comment: @teran спасибо, не заметил